Not able to see the self-signed certs for rancher by cert-manager
I am deploying rancher UI on rke2 cluster, during following their documentation, they said use cert-manager to create self signed certs for rancher.
firstly, what is the name of certificate and key (self-signed certs) created by cert-manager and I believe those certs are stored as secret in namespace of cattle-system
I can see there are many secrets got created during installation of cert-manager and rancher
k get secrets -n cattle-system

NAME TYPE DATA AGE
bootstrap-secret Opaque 1 21h
cattle-webhook-ca kubernetes.io/tls 2 20h
cattle-webhook-tls kubernetes.io/tls 2 20h
git-webhook-api-service-token-29w9p kubernetes.io/service-account-token 3 21h
helm-operation-4zsn5 Opaque 3 21h
helm-operation-759ss Opaque 3 21h
helm-operation-7hxjv Opaque 3 21h
helm-operation-8nv86 Opaque 3 21h
helm-operation-cbtvb Opaque 3 21h
helm-operation-d8kgw Opaque 3 21h
helm-operation-g7fjg Opaque 3 21h
helm-operation-kmqk7 Opaque 3 20h
helm-operation-l5nn4 Opaque 3 21h
helm-operation-qk6jh Opaque 3 21h
helm-operation-s8jk6 Opaque 3 21h
helm-operation-vxnwp Opaque 3 21h
helm-operation-w96lx Opaque 3 21h
pod-impersonation-helm-op-22lwh-token kubernetes.io/service-account-token 3 21h
pod-impersonation-helm-op-52vh4-token kubernetes.io/service-account-token 3 21h
pod-impersonation-helm-op-55kp8-token kubernetes.io/service-account-token 3 21h
pod-impersonation-helm-op-9lfcb-token kubernetes.io/service-account-token 3 20h
pod-impersonation-helm-op-gvq6d-token kubernetes.io/service-account-token 3 21h
pod-impersonation-helm-op-mc8b8-token kubernetes.io/service-account-token 3 21h
pod-impersonation-helm-op-njkzz-token kubernetes.io/service-account-token 3 21h
pod-impersonation-helm-op-p7n2n-token kubernetes.io/service-account-token 3 21h
pod-impersonation-helm-op-qvwfh-token kubernetes.io/service-account-token 3 21h
pod-impersonation-helm-op-s5qp8-token kubernetes.io/service-account-token 3 21h
pod-impersonation-helm-op-s9nlv-token kubernetes.io/service-account-token 3 21h
pod-impersonation-helm-op-wk7bp-token kubernetes.io/service-account-token 3 21h
pod-impersonation-helm-op-zrfnc-token kubernetes.io/service-account-token 3 21h
rancher-token-c8ggm kubernetes.io/service-account-token 3 21h
serving-cert kubernetes.io/tls 2 21h
sh.helm.release.v1.rancher-webhook.v1 helm.sh/release.v1 1 20h
sh.helm.release.v1.rancher.v1 helm.sh/release.v1 1 21h
tls-rancher kubernetes.io/tls 2 21h
tls-rancher-internal kubernetes.io/tls 2 21h
tls-rancher-internal-ca kubernetes.io/t

which ones for rancher to use.
Secondly, do I need to create TLS secret (tls-rancher-ingress) containing the tls.crt and tls.key?
if yes which certificates to use to create tls secret called tls-rancher-ingress.
Please advise
Thank you
I deployed cert-manager using helm to create self-signed certs for rancher and I was expecting those certs somewhere located in server location or has been created as a secret but not sure which ones are they?

When you install cert-manager, you are just installing the infrastructure to be able to manage/create TLS certificates. You mentioned that you created the self-signed certs for Rancher, but depending on the Issuer/ClusterIssuer used, it would be best to check.
If you do a kubectl get certificate -n cattle-system, you should see the certificate created by cert-manager, and describing said certificate will give you a name of the secret that was created.
Based on that list above, it could possibly be the tls-rancher-xxx secrets, but best to confirm.
To also answer your 2nd question on creation of a new certificate, you will need to create a Certificate object within Kubernetes. You can find the .yaml spec provided here.
You should also check what Issuer/ClusterIssuer was created for the self-signed certs by running kubectl get issuer or kubectl get clusterissuer. Be advised that issuers are namespaced, so you might need to check where it was put (potentially where cert-manager was installed).
